# Next.js change url without building the page using ISR

Tags: next.js, incremental-static-regeneration

I am using ISR to build static product pages using next.js. Since there are a lot of product page to generate I only generated a few pages for it. The problem that I am trying to solve is the delay in transferring the view to the product page.

So I have a category page and within it have a list of products. On each product card item, I use next.js link so that the user can go to the product page.

The problem here is the delay going to the product page when the page is not yet generated. Going to the product page is slow because next.js is building the page. I want to transfer the user to the product page immediately while showing the loading state of the page via the router.isFallback condition.

What I'm trying to achieve is the same as what a normal link would do because it shows the loading state of the page but I don't want to reload the page.

Comment: _"Is there a way to prevent next/link to build the page before transferring the the product page"_ - Unless you're using a _very_ short revalidation time, Next.js will not build the page every time a link is clicked. Also, you'll only have to wait the first time a static page gets built. Subsequents request to the page will serve the static page, and revalidate it in the background.

Comment: I did not put the revalidation time but you are correct that the subsequent request will serve the static page but its really bad user experience to build the page. What I'm trying to achieve is redirect the user right away so that it triggers the building of the static page and it shows the loading state components. right now its slow and the loading state of the component is now showing.

Comment: _"loading state of the component is now showing"_ - Are you using [`fallback: true`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-true) in `getStaticProps`? Can you show us the code for the dynamic page in question?

Comment: yes that's is what I mean. When fallback is true could should a loading state of the page. but it is currently not showing because it is building the page first before it redirects to the actual page. Therefore, the loading state of the page is not showing. The problem really is clicking the page that is not generated is lag because in the background next.js is building the static page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using next/link or router.push, use router.replace

```
   router.replace(`/product/${id"}`)
```

Let me know if this work.

Comment: Hi Stephen, it is not working and its even worse because I can't press the browser go back button.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to make the props not required,

The thing that must take time during the loading of you're ISG page of nextJs is the call api in GetStaticProps,
Something like that:

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { status, data } = await axios.get<Data>(
    `${server}/data`
  );

  if (status === 404) {
    return { notFound: true };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      ...data
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  };
}
```

But you could also decide that you will fetch the data during the loading of the state with a fall-back blocking:

```js
const MyPage = (props) => {
 const [data,setData] = useState<Data>(null);
 
 useEffect(() => {
  (function()
   const {data} = axios.get(`${server}/data`);
   setData(data);
  )()
 },[])
 
 return(
 <div>
  !data ? <div>loading ... </div> : <div>Product: {data}</div>
 </div>
 )
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }){
      return {
        props: {
         isloading: true
        },
        revalidate: 60,
      };
}
```

Comment: How do I make the props not required?

Comment: are you using TypeScript ?
you could simply not call any api during getStaticprops and send back a blank object.
And you could fetch the data after the page is render

Comment: im building the product page and I need to build the product page too for SEO reason.

Comment: Dam, so you need to wait for props to be fetch, or you could also put fallback to true:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-true

Comment: Yeah I have fallback to true too. but the problem is really about the link from the category page transitioning to product page takes too long before it changes to the product page view.

Comment: Yeah I do understand, we have the same issue, back to my company. We put some cache on the api to make it quicker to build :)